# $_SESSION returns Array

Tags: php, arrays, session, key

I have an $_SESSION['errors'] for which print_r returns Array ( [0] => field ). But when I try this:

```
   $errors = $_SESSION['error'];
    if(array_key_exists (0, $error)) {echo "yes";} else{echo "no";}
```

It outputs error: Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\wamp\www\sandbox\formvalidation\formvalidation.php on line 7

Whats wrong?

Comment: Where is the `print_r`? If it were directly above these two lines, the code would have worked and you would not have asked.

Comment: yes I started it, and print_r($_SESSION['error']) is fine, it outputs Array ( [0] => field ). Problem is with code I posted

Comment: try checking it exists too `if( (isset($_SESSION['errors'])) && (count($_SESSION['errors'])>0) ) { echo 'yes'; }`

Comment: `$_SESSION['error']` or `$_SESSION['errors']` (errors)

Comment: as per @Steve, can you confirm its error or errors?

Comment: its "error", @Waygood it returns "yes"

Comment: you know you're assigning your session to a variable called $errors but then checking the key against a variable called $error ?  since nobody else has picked up on that bit at least

Comment: yeah I know, it was miss type here but problem is still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because the `'errors'` key in the $_SESSION array does not exist. $_SESSION is an array but the `'errors'` key has not been set or does not have the value of an array.

Use this to not get that error:

```
$errors = is_array($_SESSION['errors']) ? $_SESSION['errors'] : array();
```

This uses a ternary operator to basically say:

```
$errors = IS ERRORS AN ARRAY ? YES : NO;

If yes, assign $_SESSION['errors'] to $errors;
If no, assign array() to $errors;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure $errors is a multidimensional array if you want to use array_key_exists() on it

Answer (score 0):

Try with is_arry like

```
if(is_array($errors))
{     
     if(array_key_exists (0, $errors))
     {
         echo "yes";
     }
     else
     { 
         echo "no";
     }
}
```